# Laravel: Usar slug solo para la url y mantener los id para las lareciones

Tags: laravel, url, seo

Esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::get('itinerary/{slug}/{id?}', 'TourDetailsController@show');
```

Este el controlador:

```
public function show($slug, $id)
{ 
    $tour =TourDetail::find($id); 
    $tourCities =TourDetail::find($id)->tourCities; 
    $incl=(string)TourDetail::find($id)->inclExcl->where('type',true); 
    $excl=(string)TourDetail::find($id)->inclExcl->where('type',false);

return view('tourdetails.show')->with('tour',json_decode($tour,true)) 
                               ->with('tourCities',json_decode($tourCities,true)) 
                               ->with('incl',json_decode($incl,true)) 
                               ->with('excl',json_decode($excl,true));

}
```

Con esta configuración, la url luce asi:

```
http://domain.com/itinerary/trip-name/1
```

Lo que quiero es una url tal como ésta:

```
http://domain.com/itinerary/trip-name/    (sin el id al final)
```

Con una sola tabla esto se puede lograr, pero en el controlador hace referencia a 3 tablas que se identifican con el id:

```
tour_details 
tour_cities 
incl_excls
```

COmo puedo resolver esto? Es necesario crear slug para todas las tablas?
Es posible seguir usando los IDs y usar el slug de la tabla tour_details para construir la url limpia?
O tiene una mejor solución a esto?
Espero su ayuda.